# How to distribute definitions when loading external *.m packages

Tags: parallelization

i'm struggling with the following.

I use `ParallelTable` and it works transparently as it automatically distributes the needed definitions.

However, I run into problems if inside `ParallelTable` I call a package with `Get["code/example.m"]`.
For example, the value of `const` which was set in the master kernel is not propagated in the evaluation of `Get["code/example.m"]`.

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete example of what you are doing, and a short explanation of *why* you are doing it?

Comment: I have to sample an expensive function `f[x]` over a range of `x`. And in order to calculate `f[x]` I have to `Get` the *.m package.

Comment: It looks like the problem gets fixed if I put `DistributeDefinitions["Global`"]` just before the `ParallelTable'.

Answer (score 5):

Don't ever call functions like `Get` inside `ParallelTable` because it will be difficult to control [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).  `Get` should be evaluated only once per kernel to load definitions:  to achieve this, use either `ParallelEvaluate[Get[...]]` or `ParallelNeeds` (for proper packages).

It is good practice to only place definitions inside `.m` files, and not code that computes results.  If `.m` files contain calculations instead of definitions, they are bound to use global variables.  Handling these from parallel evaluations will be difficult and error prone.

Comment: I need to call `Get` inside `ParallelTable` as the package I'm calling does things like `NDSolve`

Comment: So the `.m` file is not a package (definitions), but a program that produces results?  And those results depend on some global variables that you set in the kernel?  From the minimal information you gave, this is how I imagine it.  If you're doing this:  it's bad style and can lead to mistakes.  I suggest make the `.m`-file define functions only, and use those function in the calculation.

Comment: Yes, it is like this. I like it this way as every `.m` file does a particular job and allows my code to be modular. I would keep it this way if possible.

Comment: @Valerio If what the `.m` file does depends on global variables, then by definition the system is not modular (what it does depends on the environment).  While someone might be willing to give you a workaround which will let you keep your current setup (for that you'll need to edit your question and describe in detail what you have), the root of the problem is precisely that your setup is *not* modular.

Comment: @Valerio Also note that parallelization depends on the functions/calculations not having [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)---from your description it sounds like this might not be the case for you, or if it is, it's difficult to verify.

Comment: I guess this depends on the definition of modular. Let me explain better. I have a master.nb file which sets the parameters of the model I'm working on. Then I call the various `.m` to get results, like calculate `a` or `b`. I said that this is modular, because when I start another project, I use modularly the various `.m` files. For example I may need to do `a` and `c`.

Comment: @Valerio As I said, package up whatever your function does, and call that *function*, passing all the input to it.  Don't try to use `.m` files as functions or "subroutines".  It is just asking for trouble.